# Custom field values get deleted

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox, save-post

I created a custom post type:products which also has custom fields: price & shipping.  Occasionally, if I leave the edit product window open or refresh it, I lose the values inside price and shipping.  Can someone please advise on this.

```
add_action('save_post', 'save_details'); 
function save_details()
{ 
    global $post;
    update_post_meta($post->ID, "price",        $_POST["price"]        );
    update_post_meta($post->ID, "shipping",     $_POST["shipping"]     );
    update_post_meta($post->ID, "long_title",   $_POST["long_title"]   );
    update_post_meta($post->ID, "upload_image", $_POST["upload_image"] );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your variables before you work with them. Your save function gets a parameter `$post_id`. Use it.

From my [meta box class for a check box](https://github.com/toscho/Custom-Post-Type-Demos/blob/master/class.Toscho_Meta_Box_Checkbox.php):

```
/**
 * Saves the content to the post meta.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function save( $post_id )
{
    $this->is_allowed_save( $post_id ) and
        update_post_meta( $post_id, $this->vars['key'],
            empty ( $_POST[ $this->vars['key'] ] ) ? 'off' : 'on' );
}

/**
 * Checks if we should trigger the save action.
 *
 * @param  int  $post_id
 * @return bool
 */
protected function is_allowed_save( $post_id )
{
    // Check integrity, proper action and permission
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
    if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $this->nonce, $this->vars['title'] ) )
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
    if (    ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id )
        and ! current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id )
    )
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

As you can see, `DOING_AUTOSAVE` is something you want to avoid. Authorization is the next point, otherwise anybody can post anything to your blog. And prepare the data before you insert them into the DB.

Comment: you bet me to it but that's the location i was aiming with my comments, nice +1

Comment: Thank you! I am confused about the save function though.. can you please explain how is works?

Comment: Also, the website that I am building isn't a blog, it's a CMS which only the website owner will make changes to after logging in.

Comment: @MF1 I linked to my [Meta Box Class](https://github.com/toscho/Custom-Post-Type-Demos/blob/master/class.Toscho_Meta_Box_Checkbox.php). This is just an example code; usually I implement two levels of abstraction more. But it should tell you how it works.