# Custom Post Type with Custom Title

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, customization, taxonomy, title

I have a custom post type without title support and I'm trying to generate one from post's taxonomies and custom fields. To do so, I'm using this code:

```
function custom_post_type_title_filter( $data , $postarr )
    {
      if ($postarr['post_type'] == 'cars'){
            $id = get_the_ID();
            $engine= ', '.get_post_meta($id, 'Engine', true).'l';
            $terms = wp_get_object_terms($id, 'brand');
            $abrand= ' '.$terms[0]->name;
            $amodel = ' '.$terms[1]->name;
            $data['post_title'] = $id.$abrand.$amodel.$engine;
      }
      return $data;
    }
    add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data' , 'custom_post_type_title_filter' , 99, 2 );
```

Problem is, to make it work, I have to republish my post. It does not work with new post (it has no ID yet, I guess) and if I change custom field values in post, it won't generate name from them yet, I'll have to save it twice to get it done.

Can someone share a solution with example how it's done properly?

Also, would be nice to be able to set custom slug too (different from the title).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try the following code.

```
function custom_post_type_title ( $post_id ) {
    global $wpdb;
    if ( get_post_type( $post_id ) == 'cars' ) {
        $engine= ', '.get_post_meta($post_id, 'Engine', true).'l';
        $terms = wp_get_object_terms($post_id, 'brand');
        $abrand= ' '.$terms[0]->name;
        $amodel = ' '.$terms[1]->name;
        $title = $post_id.$abrand.$amodel.$engine;
        $where = array( 'ID' => $post_id );
        $wpdb->update( $wpdb->posts, array( 'post_title' => $title ), $where );
    }
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'custom_post_type_title' );
```

Comment: It works! Just had to set priority to 100 to work with Custom Field Template plugin. Is there any way to set custom slug too?

Comment: Yes you can set the custom slug too. You just have to update the `post_name` instead of `post_title`. But beware changing slug on every save is not a good idea, so you might want to generate the custom slug first time and save it in custom field, otherwise your posts URL will change with every update/save.

Comment: well, slug will look something like id-tax_term-tax_subterm, so it won't change very often and when it will, there will be pretty good reason for it... I guess :)

Answer (score 1):

Hook into the action `'save_post'` ([example](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/17386/custom-field-values-get-deleted/17392#17392)). You get the post ID as a parameter, and then you can do everything you did before. With one save action. :)

Comment: can you please look at my answer and see if this is the best way. Because I thought about wp_update_post but that too calls save_post. And I am not sure if there is any function to set the post title.